# C++ 11 Comparing parameter packs

Tags: c++11, variadic-templates

I am trying to wrap my head around parameter packs and need a little help.

Looking at the contrived example below, Is there a way to compare Args to T and only allow `bar()` to compile if they match? For example if I create `Task<void(int, char, float)>` I want `bar(float, char, float)` not to compile but `bar(int, char, float)` to compile just fine. Is this even feasible?

```
template <typename... Types>
struct foo {};

template<typename T>
struct Task;

template<typename R, typename...Args>
struct Task<R(Args...)>
{
    template<typename... T>
    std::enable_if<is_same<T, Args>
    void bar(T... args)
    {
        //do something here 
    }          
};

int main()
{
    Task<int(int)> task;
    int a = 0;
    float b = 1.0;
    bool c = false;

    //compiles
    task.bar(a);

    //none of these should compile
    task.bar(b);
    task.bar(c);
    task.bar(a, b);
    task.bar(a, b, c);
}
```

Comment: Maybe use tuple in `is_same`? I don't even know what is_same<T, Args> means when T and Args are parameter packs.
Or maybe I'm just misunderstanding the syntax.

Comment: There are many problems above.  If you do it without the pack, it won't compile.  Try getting your code to work with *exactly one* parameter.  Then start adding `...`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, syntax should be:

```
template<typename R, typename...Args>
struct Task<R(Args...)>
{
    template<typename... T>
    std::enable_if<is_same<tuple<T...>, tuple<Args...> >::value > bar(T... args)
    {
        //do something here 
    }          
};
```

Which compiles fine, because of SFINAE: while trying to instantiate `bar(bool)` for example, first instantiation fails with bool type, but an instantiation exists when performing conversion of parameter to int.

To get desired effect, you need the hard type check to happen after instantiating the template:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <tuple>

template<typename T>
struct Task;

template<typename R, typename... Args>
struct Task<R(Args...)>
{
    template<typename... OtherArgs>
    void bar(OtherArgs... otherArgs)
    {
        static_assert(
            std::is_same<std::tuple<Args...>, std::tuple<OtherArgs...> >::value,
            "Use same args types !"
        );
        // Do something
    }
};

int main()
{
    Task<int(int)> task;
    // Compiles fine
    task.bar(1);
    // Fails to compile
    task.bar('u');
    task.bar(0ul);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: EDIT: this is a response to a deleted comment suggesting to use `void bar(Args... args)` directly.
This would compile fine because of implicit conversion (`float`,`bool`,`char` are all implicitly convertible to `int`), which does not work as intended by the OP. You may get a warning but generally no errors (especially on someting like VC++).